# Tablet-like 12" Monitor with HDMI-In for Consoles

Tags: monitors, hdmi, video-game-console

I'm currently searching for a smaller and simpler Highdpi TV-Solution for my console and microconsole devices. The general idea is that I want a monitor with the display quality (and maybe mobility?) of a modern tablet to connect current-gen and last-gen consoles to it (PS3, PS4, Shield Console etc.).

The requirements would be as follows:

- Resolution of min. 720p, better yet 1080p
- Monitor should be between 9" and 12", the absolute maximum would be 13"
- Panel refresh at min. 50hz, supported by the connection
- IPS or similar quality panel
- Direct HDMI-Input, no streaming, no 30hz-converters, none of my video sources have USB-C or Thunderbolt, nor will they likely gain that in the future
- Has a case or case purchasable/creatable for the panel, no naked panel
- Should not be exclusive to one console like the panels that mount on top of the PS4
- Price point is around 300€ in my mind, although I will take a look at more expensive solutions if they have advantages
- Good quality, please no Alibaba-links

I already looked around but mostly found industry strength displays for embedded factories or USB-Solutions with their own graphic cards included. I would totally be open to just buying a good tablet with HDMI-In as a display mode, although I have never heard of one having that.

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Heck, if you have or can get an old laptop with a working LCD panel, you can turn the panel into an external HDMI monitor.  Instructables and MAKE have project instructions on the basics.  And LCD controller boards cost around $40 to $70.  You just need to match the LCD controller board to the LCD panel #, connect the two and you have a portable monitor.  Note:  I simplified it a bit :P  I am going to be going this route for a Raspberry Pi project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018DXABEU): GeChic 2501H 15.6" 1920x1080 Portable Monitor with HDMI, VGA Inputs. This is a battery-powered, tablet-like form-factor screen from a well-known company. It meets all requirements listed above except for the size requirement - it is about two and a half inches too wide. This product has been on the market for some time; I realize now that I had been researching a similar need a year or two ago, so the reviews available to us on store pages for the device are long-standing and reflect somewhat on its build quality and usefulness.

Answer (score 2):

Check BOOK Max3, a 13.3" E-book reader with a micro HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

In addition the the GeChic (there's 13 and 15 inch versions), there is an Acer that claims to have Mini-HDMI input:

Acer DA220HQL 21.5-Inch Android All-in-One Touchscreen Desktop 
[https://www.amazon.com/Acer-DA220HQL-21-5-Inch-Android-Touchscreen/dp/B00CHYKVPQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CHYKVPQ)
$500

Other than that there's a HD900 thing that's a bit hard to get

HD900vision - SHENZHEN G-VISION TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD
http://www.flysight.com/otherbar1734363.htm

And not much else